# Batchjob: number of record receivable by a subquery

Tags: subquery, batch-processing

I'm relatively new to Apex, but I have some questions about a batch job that I am creating. I want to make a query with a subquery (please see the code). Every Portal_*c can have more than 200 Exporte*_r.

`global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
                  String query = 'SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id FROM Exporte__r) FROM Portal__c';

            return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}`

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Portal__c> scope) {
        for (Portal__c portal : scope) {

              // doesn't work -> First error: Aggregate query has too many rows for direct assignment, use FOR loop
              // when using FOR loop -> System.QueryException: invalid query locator
              //List<Export__c> relatedExports = portal.Exporte__r;


              // grab all the related Export__c records using 'getSObjects' to avoid errors described above
              Export__c[] relatedExports = portal.getSObjects('Exporte__r');
              if (relatedExports != null) {
                    for (Export__c exp : relatedExports) {
                          // do something
                    }
              }
        }
}
```

I have the following questions:

1. If I use `List<Export__c> relatedExports = portal.Exporte__r` (which I commented out) to get the sub query records then I will receive the error message: “Aggregate query has too many rows for direct assignment, use FOR loop”. The error message makes no sense for me as the SOQL is done already before. Is there any explaination?
2. With the solution above the maximal amount of records from type Exporte_*r received per  Portal*_c with the sub query is 199 though I have more than 200 for some records of Portal__c, why is it limited to that number? It seems all records above 199 are ignored in this case.
3. Is there any possibility to receive more than 199 records from a sub query? I have tried to change the batch size but it seems it is independent of the number of records receivable by the sub query. Any idea?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As per the salesforce doc http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_loops_for_SOQL.htm

> You might get a QueryException in a SOQLfor loop with the message
>   Aggregate query has too many rows for direct assignment, use FOR loop.
>   This exception is sometimes thrown when accessing a large set of child
>   records of a retrieved sObject inside the loop, or when getting the
>   size of such a record set. To avoid getting this exception, use a for
>   loop to iterate over the child records, as follows.
>
> ```
> Integer count=0;
> for (Contact c : returnedAccount.Contacts) {
>     count++;
>     // Do some other processing
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using inner query in the query of the batch's query locator. change the start query to this

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
              String query = 'SELECT Id, Name FROM Portal__c';

        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
```

}

Then in the execute to query the required Exporte__r records. In this query remember to put limit etc otherwise you will get too many DML rows error again.